# How to pass a variable from a Node.js file to a script.js file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, variables

I have a Node.js script that run my website and there are some variables in it that I would like to pass to a script.js file embedded in my html page.
 How can I achieve that?

I leave some code to explain me better.
This is the Node variable I want to use later:

```js
const startTime = process.argv.slice(2);
```

And this is what I would like to do in script.js:

```js
console.log(startTime);
```

Thanks in advance for helping me out!

Comment: you can import your javascript file ```node.js``` in your html file and call the method

Comment: There are probably a few different ways that this could be accomplished. Is your Node.js acting as a web server or an API server? That would make a difference in how to approach a solution.

Comment: You can render it to html page as global variable, or send it on api request.

Answer (score 0):

You can [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) variables and functions just like you import them.

But a better approach would be passing the `function` instead of passing the `variables`.

Define the function in a `file.js`:

```
// file.js    
const sayHello = (name) => {console.log('Hello ' + name)}
```

then use `export` to make it available in other js files.

In your `script.js` file, import the function from `file.js`:

```
// script.js    
import {sayHello} from './file.js';
```

and now you can use sayHello in your `script.js`.

```
// script.js    
sayHello('Jack');
```